# `Missing required parameter : id` after a successful update

Tags: php, yii2

why did I get this bad request (#400) error after submitting my update on my 'news' section :

> Missing required parameters: id

This is my update function

php

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $oldFile = $model->getImageFile();
    $currentImage=$model->image;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {           
        // process uploaded image file instance
        $image = $model->uploadImage();
        // revert back if no valid file instance uploaded
        if ($image === false) {
            $model->image = $currentImage;
        }
        if ($model->save()) {
            // upload only if valid uploaded file instance found
            if ($image !== false && unlink($oldFile)) { // delete old and overwrite
                $path = $model->getImageFile();
                $image->saveAs($path);
            }
            return $this->redirect(['view', ['id'=>$model->id,'image'=>$model->image],
        ]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
    }
}

public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Please note that the updating and uploading image process were actually a success (that's why I didn't show my model's method code that my actionUpdate called).  If I go directly to view the recently updated page and view the content, it clearly displays the updated contents along with the image without problem. The error only occurs just right after the update is submitted.  I thought I had pass the parameter after the update by this line :

```
return $this->redirect(['view', ['id'=>$model->id,'image'=>$model->image],
```

Right before that line I even echo $model->id to test and it echoed out the id.

I've looked for similar problem in StackOverflow and find someone suggested this :
php

```
if($model->save())
{
    $lastInsertID = $model->getPrimaryKey();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $lastInsertID]);
}
```

But it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: in your else statement you are not returning model instead of id

Comment: `return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->id,'image'=>$model->image]);` instead of `return $this->redirect(['view', ['id'=>$model->id,'image'=>$model->image]]);`

Comment: Thanks @Insane Skull, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass URL as flat array:

```
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id,'image' => $model->image]);
```